# NodeJS Stream Drain Out of Memory issue

Tags: node.js, express, stream, out-of-memory

I have an issue trying to retrieve data from elasticsearch (OS Ubuntu, node v4.2.6, res object comes from express as a writable stream).

I am not using elasticsearch.js driver here on purpose. If I use ES driver, result remains the same.

Here is my code :

```
   function getNextChunk() {
      console.log(process.memoryUsage());
      console.log("Getting chunks...");
      var options = { method : 'POST', url :  myHost + '/_search/scroll',
                      json : true,
                      body : { scroll: '60s', scroll_id: globalScope.scrollId }};
      request.post(options, function (err, resp, data) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        if (!data.hits.hits.length) { console.log("Done!"); return res.end(); }
        if (!res.write(JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits)))
          res.once('drain', function() { console.log("Draining..."); process.nextTick(getNextChunk); })
        else 
          process.nextTick(getNextChunk);
    });
}
```

Here is output :

```
{ rss: 165621760, heapTotal: 140918368, heapUsed: 116827240 }
Getting chunks...
Draining...
{ rss: 178941952, heapTotal: 153020000, heapUsed: 122942472 }
Getting chunks...
Draining...
{ rss: 191905792, heapTotal: 164065120, heapUsed: 140290016 }
Getting chunks...
```

(...)

```
Draining...
{ rss: 402944000, heapTotal: 358359648, heapUsed: 328087560 }
Getting chunks...
Draining...
{ rss: 414441472, heapTotal: 369453920, heapUsed: 345375496 }
Getting chunks...
Killed
```

As you can see, heapUsed is increasing until process get killed by OS. I guess I am missing something somewhere, but I can't figure out.

By the way, I tried to write each hit one by one with drain event, but still the same...

**Edit from here**

I did a new test with this code :

```
var data = {};

function safeWrite(err, resp, newData) {
  if (newData) data = newData;
  if (err) return console.log('Error !');
  if (!data.hits.hits.length) return console.log('Done !');
  while (data.hits.hits.length) {
    if (!res.write(JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits.pop()))) {
      res.once('drain', safeWrite);
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!data.hits.hits.length)
    process.nextTick(getNextChunk);
}

function getNextChunk() {
  console.log(process.memoryUsage());
  console.log("Getting chunks...");
  var options = { method : 'POST', url :  myHost + '/_search/scroll',
                  json : true,
                  body : { scroll: '1m', scroll_id: state.scrollId }};
  request.post(options, safeWrite);
}

getNextChunk();
```

What is funny, is that if I call express from another AWS server, it gives the same result. Memory is increasing fast, and crashes node. If I call from a slow connection, garbage collector put memory back to its starting level. Is it possible that garbage collector does not have time to do its job ? I don't think so, but...

Thanks for you help !